# I have a problem: RecyclerView showing wrong data when scrolling

Tags: android

1.I have a problem: RecyclerView showing wrong data when scrolling, I put if- 
   else condition in  onBindViewHolder()  for showing Description text on Child 
   Item on particular condition, First time when populate list it is showing 
   correct but after scrolling list its showing wrong.

```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
     final ContentItem content = values.get(position);
     holder.txtName.setText(content.getName());
       if( holder.txtDescription.equals("hasDescription"))
            {
                  holder.txtHeader.setText(content.getDescription());
            }  
   }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you post your complete code for adapter class?

Comment: if( holder.txtDescription.equals("hasDescription")) where did you find this hasDescription on textview?

Answer (score 6):

looks like you are missing to override some methods. you need to override below methods.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you're seeing items that shouldn't have a description with a description.

This is the nature of a recycler view. Like the name suggests, you must recycle your items. Basically, items that have already been used, will be reused. In your case, if an item had a description and now it's not suppose to then you need to clean this up too:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
   final ContentItem content = values.get(position);
   holder.txtName.setText(content.getName());
   if( holder.txtDescription.equals("hasDescription")) {
        holder.txtHeader.setText(content.getDescription());
   }  else{
        holder.txtHeader.setText("");
   }
}
```

As you can see, this way everyone an item is not suppose to have a description, you clean it up.

Comment: That's it, having an else setting another value fixed it. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
     final ContentItem content = values.get(position);
     holder.txtName.setText(content.getName());
       if( holder.txtDescription.equals("hasDescription"))
            {
                  holder.txtHeader.setText(content.getDescription());
            }  
      else{
                 holder.txtHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this if "hasDescription" is fetching from API :

```
 @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
     final ContentItem content = values.get(position);
     holder.txtName.setText(content.getName());
       if(content.getDescription.equals("hasDescription"))
            {
                  holder.txtHeader.setText(content.getDescription());
            }  
   }
```